# "Snap to Grid" behaviour for a dojo.dnd.Moveable node in Xpages

Tags: dojo, xpages

**Context :** I'm fairly new to Xpages (8.5.3), Dojo and JS, and I want to create a wysiwyg template editor : the users can drag and drop items (images representing fields, datepickers, ...) anywhere on the page, and when they hit the save button, the position of these items is saved.

The simple page below shows how I make a panel moveable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view id="xp01" xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    dojoTheme="true" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" styleClass="claro">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.dojo"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.dnd.Source"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.dnd.Moveable"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:table id="dndSourceTable" border="1">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td id="ds1" dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source"
                style="color:red;"> THIS IS THE BOX
                <xp:panel id="mov1"
                    style="height:32.0px;width:160.0px; margin:0px;background-color:rgb(192,192,192)"
                    dojoType="dojo.dnd.Moveable">THIS IS MOVEABLE 
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

The code above works, but I'd like to make the panel Snap to Grid. I found [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/dnd/Moveable.html) in the dojo documentation, that explains how to make a custom Mover with a Snap to Grid option, but I can't figure out how to implement that in Xpages.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my own solution, based on Naveen's suggestion to use jQuery.

**The problem** : Dojo has no real snap to grid capability, or this has not been correctly documented. Using jQuery is much, much easier. Here a very simple exemple.

For beginners like me : jQuery / jQuery UI aren't provided with Domino, but it is very simple to add them inside your Notes Database (*.nfs). This means that they will move along with your db if you move it.

1. **Download jQuery UI** (jQuery incl.) from http://jqueryui.com/ .I chose the whole package but I reckon you could just select "Core" and "Interactions". You will end up with a zip file.
2. **Include jQUery/ jQueryUI in your database** :

   - In Domino Designer, click on "Window - Open Perspective> - Xpages". This perspective (=workspace) has the "Package Explorer" tab in the left of Designer.
   - Use Package Explorer to navigate to the 'WebContent' folder of your db.
   - Drop the 'css' folder and the 'js' folder from the zip file into 'WebContent'.
3. **Include jQuery/jQueryUI in your Xpage**. Simply add this code in your source code (the name of your jQuery/jQueryUI files may be different)

`<xp:this.resources>

        <xp:script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>

        <xp:script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" clientSide="true">

        </xp:script>

    </xp:this.resources>

    <script> XSP.addOnLoad(function(){ 
        $("[id='view:_id1:MyPan01']").draggable({ grid: [ 80, 80 ] });

        })

        </script>`

This makes a Panel named "MyPan01" draggable and snapping on a 80*80 grid.

Here is the complete code for my page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
        <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" clientSide="true">
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Intro
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:panel id="MyPan01"
        style="height:120px;width:120px;background-color:rgb(255,128,192)">
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Outro
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <script>
 XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
  $("[id='view:_id1:MyPan01']").draggable({ grid: [ 80, 80 ] });
  })
  </script>
    </xp:view>
```

From there, you can explore and adapt. Thanks again to Naveen for the tips !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [`dojox.layout.GridContainer`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/layout/GridContainer.html) and [`dojox.widget.Portlet`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/widget/Portlet.html). They provided out-of-box functionality for snap to grid.

Basically you add `dojox.widget.Portlet` in `dojox.layout.GridContainer` and specify how many cells you want in your grid, which portlets can be dragged, which cannot and so on.

An example of Portlet in Grid Container can be found **[here](http://www.skynet.ie/~sos/misc/dojo/dojox/widget/tests/test_PortletInGridContainer.html)**.

Incorporating it in your XPage shouldn't be that difficult with importing necessary dojo modules in your resources and using `dojoType` attribute (which you have already done in your example).

Comment: The URL didn't work for. It shows error of `The requested URL /view/2f25eb75-78d0-4076-89ec-92e651e55a29.jpg> was not found on this server.`

Comment: Oh, sorry. this is the url, and it works for me : http://tof.canardpc.com/view/2f25eb75-78d0-4076-89ec-92e651e55a29.jpg

Comment: And now i managed to erase my first comment. So sorry about that. Here it is : Hello @Naveen, and thanks a lot for your input. I was able to use those dojo components, thanks to you. 

However, GridContainer is not a real "grid", it's just columns, so it's impossible to specify the horizontal position of the portlets, except if you glue together a serie of containers, but they can't overlap. 

I'm looking for a real grid to snap my panels (or divs, or whatever) to. That's why dnd.moveable was promising.

http://tof.canardpc.com/view/2f25eb75-78d0-4076-89ec-92e651e55a29.jpg .

Comment: @FrancoisBarnich: You should probably look into some other JavaScript libraries like jQuery which might have the functionality you are lookign for.

Answer (score 0):

The dojo moveable class suports several events (onMoveStart, onMoveStop, ...) as you can check in the documentation. I use "onMove" to implement snap-to-grid on move operations.

How ?

The code below assumes that you already have a myMoveable object of the dojo class Moveable, assumes that gridPattern is a javascript variable with an integer value corresponding to the grid spacing you want, and also assumes you are using the dojo "on" module instead of the old "connect" module (this is recommended for dojo versions 1.7 and above). Remember that with the new "on" module, the event name loses the "on" prefix (documented in pre dojo 1.7 versions): "onStart"  becomes "Start" and so on. Applying the same rule, "onMove" becomes "Move" (the second parameter in our move handler).

```
myMoveHandler=on(myMoveable, "Move", function (mover,leftTop,e){//called at every move step
    this.onMoving(mover, leftTop);
    var s = mover.node.style;
    s.left = snapToGrid(leftTop.l,gridPattern) + "px";
    s.top  = snapToGrid(leftTop.t,gridPattern) + "px";
    this.onMoved(mover, leftTop);
});
```

snapToGrid is a simple function that for a given coordinate and gridPattern returns the same coordinate  according to that grid pattern.

```
snapToGrid=function(xVal,gridPattern){ 
    var xMod=xVal%gridPattern;
    if(xMod==0) //no transform
       return(xVal);
    if(xMod<gridPattern/2) //snap no number below
       return(xVal-xMod);
    return(xVal+(gridPattern-xMod));
};
```